# ASP.NET MVC C# application to reset and change password., error when "User must change password on login is selected " ,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, passwords

I have created an ASP.NET MVC application using C#, to reset and change password. I get an error when the "Active Directory: User must change password at next login" option is selected. It's working fine when this option is not selected.

How can my application allow to change password when the option "User must change password at Next login" is selected?